# Make mmenu.js open on widescreen and can also be closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I'm making my menu made with mmenu.js to open when opened on widescreen and closed on medium to mobile. But I also want, on widescreen, to be able to close it with the toggle button.

Right now, you can only close it while on mobile.

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/p9ynx8wc/)

```
        $(function() {
            var $menu = $('nav#menu'),
                $html = $('html, body');

            $menu.mmenu({
                extensions: ["widescreen", "theme-dark"]
            });

            var $anchor = false;
            $menu.find( 'li > a' ).on(
                'click',
                function( e )
                {
                    $anchor = $(this);
                }
            );

            var api = $menu.data( 'mmenu' );
            api.bind( 'closed',
                function()
                {
                    if ( $anchor )
                    {
                        var href = $anchor.attr( 'href' );
                        $anchor = false;

                        //  if the clicked link is linked to an anchor, scroll the page to that anchor 
                        if ( href.slice( 0, 1 ) == '#' )
                        {
                            $html.animate({
                                scrollTop: $( href ).offset().top
                            }); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a fake button to look just like the mmenu button.

```
<a href="#fake-bttn"></a>
```

Then add jquery to toggle a class on the #my-mmenu container and .mm-page container.

```
$("#fake-bttn").click(function(){
    $("my-mmenu").toggleClass("close");
    $("div.mm-page").toggleClass("close");  
});
```

Then add the following to the widesceen.css for mmenu.

```
.mm-slideout {
  -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: width 1s;
}
.mm-page.mm-slideout.close {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin-left: 0% !important;
}
.mm-menu.mm-widescreen {
  -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: width 1s;
  min-width: 0% !important;
}
.mm-menu.mm-widescreen.close {
  min-width: 0% !important;
  width: 0% !important;
}
```

I also had to add a float right to my .mm-page container in the widescreen.css

```
.mm-page { float:right }
```

Then hide the button based on the same media query value you have for the widescreen.css.